# Request to other route in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I make a request to another route in node.js? 
I have POST request and after successful POST request I want to do GET request to get date this user.

```
app.post("/childrens", checkUser, async (req, res, next) => {
    ...
    const childrenResponse = await Childrens.create({
            ...children,
            id_kindergarten,
            type: 2
        })
    //here I want make get request after successful POST request
    const data = app.get("/childrens/2");
    res.send(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commonly this is handled with a `303 See Other` including a `Location` header for the other resource. In your case:

```
res
  .set('Location', '/childrens/2')
  .status(303)
  .send();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `handle` method like so:

```
req.method = "GET";
req.url = "/childrens/2";
app._router.handle(req, res, next);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, it working in my case.

```
app.use('/users', function(req, res, next){
  console.log('users');
});

app.use('/test', function(req, res, next){
  console.log('test');
  req.url = '/users';
  return app._router.handle(req, res, next);
});
```

output :

```
GET /test - - ms - -
test
users
```